# How to put an echo inside a div that's inside an echo

Tags: php, wordpress, echo, buddypress

I am trying to call Buddy Press' avatar and replace my Newspaper theme's avatar in the menu.  How do I put this code:

```
    echo bp_core_fetch_avatar( array(
        'item_id' => bp_loggedin_user_id(),
        'width' => 21,
        'height' => 21,
        'class' => 'avatar',
        )
    );
```

Inside the

```
    <div class="td-avatar-container"></div>
```

class?

```
   <?php

    //get current logd in user data

    global $current_user;

    echo '
    <div class="td-logged-wrap">
            <div class="td-menu-avatar">
                 <div class="td-avatar-container">' .   bp_core_fetch_avatar ($current_user->ID, 80) .  '</div>
            </div>

    <div class="td-menu-username"><a href="' . bp_core_get_user_domain($current_user->ID) . '" class="td_user_logd_in">' . $current_user->display_name . '</a></div>
    <div class="td-menu-logout"><a href="' . wp_logout_url(home_url( '/' )) . '">' . __td('Logout', TD_THEME_NAME) . '</a></div>
</div>
    ';
```

Thanks! I keep getting white screens, and this is the very last thing I need for this feature to go live! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you see white screen, it means the error reporting is turned off, you should turn it on in your development environment

Comment: Thanks for response. At this point I'm just editing files in cpanel.

Comment: this is horrible, you should  never directly change  your production code, also the online editor sucks!

Comment: put some work to setup a dev environment , trust me your productivity will increase so much more

Comment: You're right. I've used Eclipse for bigger projects before, but I'm just trying to patch this menu up. Buddy press + newspaper theme (#1 theme) isn't meshing well.

Answer (score 2):

You can stop and start PHP within html any time.

```
<div class="td-logged-wrap">
  <div class="td-menu-avatar">
        <div class="td-avatar-container">

        <?php echo' .   bp_core_fetch_avatar ($current_user->ID, 80) .  '; ?>

        </div>
  </div>

<div class="td-menu-username"><a href="

<?php echo' . bp_core_get_user_domain($current_user->ID) . '; ?>

" class="td_user_logd_in"><?php echo' . $current_user->display_name . '; ?>

</a></div>

<div class="td-menu-logout"><a href="<?php echo' . wp_logout_url(home_url( '; ?> / <?php echo' )) . '; ?>"><?php echo' . __td('; ?>Logout<?php echo', TD_THEME_NAME) . '; ?></a>
</div>
```

Comment: bp_core_fetch_avatar ($current_user->ID, 80) isn't working. Is there a way to insert the array from above in its place?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't quite answer your question, but will help you see why you are having the problem.
Change the following in the wp-config.php in order to see the errors and you can debug from there:
define('WP_DEBUG', true);